# Remove inputs when deleting row from database

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I create the form to edit dynamically like this:

```
<button href="s11" class="btn btn-warning caixa btn-show close-sidebar upd_orc" data-element="#minhaDiv10" style="float:right;"><i class="fa fa-folder-open fa-5x taman" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<br>
<h4>Editar Orçamento</h4>
</button>
<section id="s11">
    <div class="welcome" style="display:none" id="minhaDiv10">
      <form role="form" action="#!" id="retorc1">
      </form>
    </div>
</section>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('click', '.upd_orc', function(){ 
 var updo = document.querySelector('input[name="updorc"]:checked').value;
   $.ajax({  
     url:"updorc1.php",  
     method:"POST",
     cache: false,              
     data:{updo:updo},              
     dataType:"json",  
     success:function(data1){
        var linha1 = ``;
        for (var i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) { 
          Id = data1[i][0];
          Ref = data1[i][4];
          Designacao = data1[i][5];

          linha1 += `<button class="btn btn-danger caixa btn-show close-sidebar delete_prod" style="float:right;"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-5x taman" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                 <br>
                 <h4>Eliminar Produto</h4>
                 </button>  
                 <input type="radio" style="float:right;" name="eliprod[]" class="rest" value="${ Id }">
                 <div class="form-group col-md-2">  
                 <input type="text" class="form-control1" name="Refe[]" value="${Ref}">
                 <span class="form-highlight"></span>
                 <span class="form-bar"></span>
                 <label class="label1" for="Refe">Refª</label>        
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group col-md-6">  
                 <input type="text" class="form-control1" name="Designaca[]" value="${Designacao}">
                 <span class="form-highlight"></span>
                 <span class="form-bar"></span>
                 <label class="label1" for="Designaca">Designação</label>        
                 </div>`;
                 $("#retorc1").html(linha1);
                }
        });
});
```

Notice that in the form inside the js there is a button to delete and an input radio to pick up the line id since it returns more than one line.

The form looks like this:

[image]

To remove I select the radio input and click on the button to delete.

To delete it in the database I do it this way:

```
$(document).on("click", ".delete_prod", function(){
  var Id = document.querySelector('input[name="eliprod[]"]:checked').value;
  if(confirm('Tem certeza de que deseja remover o produto do orçamento?'))
  {
    $.ajax({
       url: 'delorc.php',
       type: 'GET',
       data: {Id: Id},
       error: function() {
          alert('Algo está errado!');
       },
       success: function(data) {
          alert("Produto removido com sucesso");
       }
     });
   }
});
```

This way it correctly eliminates in the database, but it does not remove from the form the inputs associated with the values ​​removed in the database.

I wanted it to also eliminate the inputs on the form so that the user does not have to update the page to keep the data up to date.

I'm trying this way:

```
   for (var i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) { 
      Id = data1[i][0];
      Ref = data1[i][4];
      Designacao = data1[i][5];

      linha1 += `<button class="btn btn-danger caixa btn-show close-sidebar delete_prod" style="float:right;"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-5x taman" aria-hidden="true"></i>
             <br>
             <h4>Eliminar Produto</h4>
             </button>
             <div class="teste2">  
             <input type="radio" style="float:right;" name="eliprod[]" class="rest" value="${ Id }">
             <div class="form-group col-md-2">
             <input type="text" class="form-control1" name="Refe[]" value="${Ref}">
             <span class="form-highlight"></span>
             <span class="form-bar"></span>
             <label class="label1" for="Refe">Refª</label>        
             </div>
             <div class="form-group col-md-6">  
             <input type="text" class="form-control1" name="Designaca[]" value="${Designacao}">
             <span class="form-highlight"></span>
             <span class="form-bar"></span>
             <label class="label1" for="Designaca">Designação</label>        
             </div>
             </div>`;
             $("#retorc1").html(linha1);
            }
```

In the html I added `<div class="test2">`.

Then in js I added within the success `$(".teste2").remove();`.

But this way it eliminates all the inputs and I should only eliminate the inputs associated with the id of the line that I am deleting in the database

Comment: Refetch the data and load it using AJAX after deleting.

Comment: @Gnanavel I've tried, but it doesn't destroy the form that is and build the form again, at least it didn't work for me. But isn't there a simpler way through js or jquery without having to rebuild the form?

Comment: If you had all the inputs for each item in their own `<div>`, it would be easy to remove that entire `<div>` from the DOM. I suggest you do it that way, so after successfully deleting the row from the DB, the click handler would get its parent `<div>` and just delete it.

Comment: @kmoser Can you put just one example to better understand what you explained?

Comment: @Bruno If you [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64289379/edit) to include an example of the rendered HTML on the page, I'll show you a modified version that will allow you to do what I'm suggesting.

Comment: @kmoser I already edited the question with the html

Comment: @Bruno See my answer with code that should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap each section in a `<div>` with an `id` to identify it. I've just changed the first and last line of your existing code:

```
linha1 += `<div id="produto-${ Id }">
    <button class="btn btn-danger caixa btn-show close-sidebar delete_prod" style="float:right;"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-5x taman" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <br>
    <h4>Eliminar Produto</h4>
    </button>  
    <input type="radio" style="float:right;" name="eliprod[]" class="rest" value="${ Id }">
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">  
    <input type="text" class="form-control1" name="Refe[]" value="${Ref}">
    <span class="form-highlight"></span>
    <span class="form-bar"></span>
    <label class="label1" for="Refe">Refª</label>        
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">  
    <input type="text" class="form-control1" name="Designaca[]" value="${Designacao}">
    <span class="form-highlight"></span>
    <span class="form-bar"></span>
    <label class="label1" for="Designaca">Designação</label>        
    </div>
</div>`;

$(document).on("click", ".delete_prod", function(){
  var Id = document.querySelector('input[name="eliprod[]"]:checked').value;
  if(confirm('Tem certeza de que deseja remover o produto do orçamento?'))
  {
    $.ajax({
       url: 'delorc.php',
       type: 'GET',
       data: {Id: Id},
       error: function() {
          alert('Algo está errado!');
       },
       success: function(data) {
          $('#produto-' + Id).remove(); // Remove the entire div containing that product
          alert("Produto removido com sucesso");
       }
     });
   }
});
```

Then, modify your `click` handler to delete the corresponding `<div>` that was clicked. See my comment below for the one modified line:

```
$(document).on("click", ".delete_prod", function(){
  var Id = document.querySelector('input[name="eliprod[]"]:checked').value;
  if(confirm('Tem certeza de que deseja remover o produto do orçamento?'))
  {
    $.ajax({
       url: 'delorc.php',
       type: 'GET',
       data: {Id: Id},
       error: function() {
          alert('Algo está errado!');
       },
       success: function(data) {
          $('#produto-' + Id).remove(); // Remove the entire div containing that product
          alert("Produto removido com sucesso");
       }
     });
   }
});
```